# Quartz Cron Schedule Not Triggering

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I used this trigger to run job every 1 hour from 12 AM- 8 AM. But this is not triggering at all. Is this expression correct?

```
0 0/60 12,8 * * ?
```

Comment: Just correct expression doesn't guarantee that the job will get trigger.

Comment: Your expression will fire exactly at 12:00 AM **and** 8:00 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [this site](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to build and check expressions based on "*Quartz Cron*" format.

The correct expression is this:

```
0 0 0-8 * * ?
```